# Text, logo and hamburger on background image

Tags: html, css, web, layout, scale

I'm laying out the layout [Figma Layout](https://www.figma.com/file/2rdy1qjBTl7D6BAC8S4qlf/Webovio?node-id=0%3A2). This page has a background image and additional

Background

[image: Wallpaper]

Additional - logo

[image: Logo]

and a hamburger

[image: Hamburger]

There is html code of the page

```css
:root {
  --my-screenwidth: 1366px;
  --my-screenheight: 768px;
  --layout-screenwidth: 1441px;
  --layout-screenheight: 811px;
}

._container {
  --layout-containerwidth: 1111px;
  --layout-containerheight: 43px;
  max-width: calc((var(--layout-containerwidth)/var(--layout-screenwidth))*var(--my-screenwidth));
  margin: 0px auto;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:regular,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Webovio</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <main class="page">
      <div class="page__main-block main-block">
        <div class="main-block__container _container">
          <div class="margin-block__header">
            <div class="main-block__nav">
              <!--
                        <img src="img/triangles/white-triangle.png" class="main-block__logo_white_triangle" alt="logoheader">
                        <img src="img/triangles/yellow-triangle.png" class="main-block__logo_yellow_triangle" alt="logoheader">
                        -->
              <!--<div class="main-block__header_image_1">-->
              <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB0ua.png" class="main-block__logo_name" alt="logoname">
              <!--</div>-->
              <!--<div class="main-block__header_image_2"></div>-->
              <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO056.png" class="main-block__logo_hamburger_icon" alt="menulogo">
              <!--</div>-->
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="main-block__body">
            <div class="main-block__smalltitle">A place where</div>
            <div class="main-block__title">A creative agency for redemptive brands</div>
            <!--
                        <div class="main-block__text">
                            Anteelo is a leading strategic design firm that builds powerful digital solutions for startups and enterprises.
                        </div>
                        -->
            <div class="main-block__items">
              <!--<a href="" class="main-block__link main-block__link_yellow">Get in touch link</a>-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="main-block__image _ibg">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tju6g.png" alt="cover">
        </div>


      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The css contains the dimensions of the header containing the logo and the hamburger. Here is the `max-width: calc((var(--layout-containerwidth)/var(--layout-screenwidth))*var(--my-screenwidth));` which calculates the maximum width of the header given the width values my screen and the layout screen, as well as the width of the header on the layout, taken from the figma layout (the header consists of a logo and a hamburger).

Tell me how to layout the layout so that **so that the logo and the hamburger in the header take their places on the background image, and so that the text (headings A place where and A creative agency for redemptive brands) becomes left horizontally and in the middle vertically of the image, and also to be able to proportionally scale the background image as in [Proportional scaling tools](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1430091/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#1430094)**. It should be like on [Layout from Figma](https://www.figma.com/file/2rdy1qjBTl7D6BAC8S4qlf/Webovio?node-id=0%3A2). I tried to style but couldn't get the text, logo and hamburger on the background image.

P.S. Exact indents are not needed. Tell me how to layout so that the background image has the content of the page, including text, logo and hamburger.

Answer (score 0):

Section is set to be `height: 100vh; width: 100vw` and then `display: grid`.

The background image will always fill it's container and you can control the image cropping by adding `style="--imgPosition: <X> <Y>"`, which is just laying out to [object-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position) so you can check MDN for potential values.

Content in the main block is using `display: grid` as well and all set to occupy the same space. The links have an explicit `z-index` set so they will be above the content. The content will always be vertically centered unless it has more content than screen height, at which point `padding: 6rem 0` will add 6rem above and below the section

```css
*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: border-box } body { color: white; font: 16px "Poppins", sans-serif; margin: 0 }

section.custom {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh; width: 100vw;
  place-items: center;
}
section.custom > * {
  grid-area: 1/1/-1/-1;
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
}

section.custom .back { position: relative }
section.custom .back > * {
  display: block;
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: var(--imgPosition, center center);
  position: absolute;
}

section.custom .fore {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 1rem;
  place-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
section.custom .fore > * { grid-area: 1/1/-1/-1 }

section.custom .fore .navLink { align-self: start; z-index: 1 }
section.custom .fore #logo { justify-self: start }
section.custom .fore #menuToggle { justify-self: end }
section.custom .fore .block { padding: 6rem 0; width: 100% }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:regular,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />


<section class="custom">
  <div class="back" style="--imgPosition: top left"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tju6g.png"></div>
  <div class="fore">
    <a class="navLink" id="logo" href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB0ua.png"></a>
    <a class="navLink" id="menuToggle" href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO056.png"></a>
    <div class="block">
      <p>A place where</p>
      <h1>A creative agency for redemptive brands</h1>
      <p>Anteelo is a leading strategic design firm that builds powerful digital solutions for startups and enterprises.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you edit the code so that the background image is proportionally scalable?

Comment: @wfamilyweb can you elaborate exactly what you mean by proportionally scalable